# buildroot & DT overlays (ADS7846)

Tags: raspberry-pi, buildroot

maybe someone of you can help me:

I have to make a custom linux build via buildroot. I have to use an attached LCD, which uses the ADS7846 driver, and I struggle to get it working. I included the resp. settings in config.txt, as provided by the LCD manufacturer, but dmesg would not reveal the hardware being recognized when booting the system.

When I do the same on a freshly installed Raspbian (that is, just include the required params in config.txt), I can verify that the driver loads successfully.

I made the kernel DT'able with mkknlimg and I can verify that it works - /proc/device-tree is present.

So what do I have to do to make this work? I'm lost...

any help greatly appreciated!

thanks a bunch,
    Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

in the meanwhile, I found the solution. I needed to include udev support for the kernel to recognize the touch screen.